# Error configuring phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

After installing the configuration began, however I kept getting this message saying:

```
 An error occurred while installing the database:                                
  │                                                                                 
  │ ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket          
  │ '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I am new to this not sure what is blocking the mysql socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a typical permission problem, you need to ensure that your permissions can correctly read and write the database sock file.

> **[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084959/1892635)**
>
> If your file my.cnf (usually in the */etc/mysql/* folder) is correctly
>   configured with:
>
> ```
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> ```
>
> You can check if mysql is running with the following command:
>
> ```
> mysqladmin -u root -p status
> ```
>
> Try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can try:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
> ```

If the above doesn't fix the problem then its likely something else, Visit [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38) on Stack Overflow for more answers.

Comment: seems like it has worked (y) 
` mysqladmin -u root -p status 
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`

then setting the permission:

`mysqladmin -u root -p status 
Enter password: 
Uptime: 4067  Threads: 3  Questions: 3055  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 163  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 156  Queries per second avg: 0.751`

Answer (score 0):

That's an error in configuration. You need to put localhost or your IP in it.

Follow this steps:

1. Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.
2. Find `bind-address`, and change its value to the database server host machine's IP address. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
3. Save and close the file.
4. Restart apache

Comment: this is already `bind-address            = 127.0.0.1` although machine IP is `10.10.10.4` which is going to change in future when I change the router.